# forex-python Currency Rates Source Not Ready

Tags: python, forex, currency-exchange-rates

I'm having a problem using forex-python, every call i do to get-rate() return to me an "Currency Rates Source Not Ready", is forex-python still running or am i the problem??

```
c = CurrencyRates()
c.get_rates('USD')
```

===> Currency Rates Source Not Ready